# API with optional query string is losing the route value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to have a WebAPI path that takes an Id, but also, an optional query.

So, usually, the client will send:

```
http://localhost:49487/api/template/5b31b31c-ecd9-4e7a-bcdb-1c263399c86f
```

But sometimes, I need to return a bit of extra details in the payload. So I want them to send:

```
http://localhost:49487/api/template/5b31b31c-ecd9-4e7a-bcdb-1c263399c86f?IncludePreview=true
```

My .Net Web API Controller enpoint is defined like this, and handles the first case.

```
[Route("{Id}"), HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetTemplate(Guid Id, bool IncludePreview = false)
```

But as soon as I sent the second version, with the query string, the api controller fires (I have a breakpoint on it), but, Id is always Guid.Empty.

How can I have my API method accept both versions? Or do I need to create a separate endpoint for both versions?

Comment: Change it to [FromQuery] bool IncludePreview

Comment: MVC comes with `[FromQuery]` attribute, which restricts binding of the data to query string only, but it still treats them as optional if we use it

Comment: The code is for asp.net-core but your tag is for asp.net-web-api, which is usually associated with older version of web api. which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the Include Preview Boolean value as a fixed value. So event though your call catches the IncludePreview=true in GetTemplate method ,it get reassign. Please try to use a nullable Boolean with 'null' as assigned value.

```
public IActionResult GetTemplate(Guid Id, bool? IncludePreview=null)
```